# Checking for the end of a string without using arrays, etc

Tags: java, string

My program needs to read a string and process each character, one at a time. I don't want to put the string into a `char` array, so is there any way to check for the end of the string without doing this? I tried to do this (where s is a String): `s.charAt(index) != null` as a condition for a `while` loop, but I shortly figured out that this obviously doesn't work, because you just can't use != with char and null. Is there any other way?

Comment: `for (int index = 0; index < s.length(); index++)`...

Comment: Are you aware that a String already _is_ a char array?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean by "checking for the end".  Strings aren't null-terminated, so the fact that a String is a size > 0 means that there's an end at the last character.

Comment: Just call `s.length()` to determine the length of the string!!

Comment: Oh yes, I understand now, thank you. (I'm an amateur Java programmer, so please forgive the silly mistakes...!) Thank you, MadProgrammer, that was the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest loop through a string one character at a time would simply use the length of the string to handle this.  For example:

```
if (inputString != null) {
  for (int i=0; i < imputString.length(); i++) {
     theChar = inputString.charAt(i);
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try comparing your `index` variable to `s.length()`:

```
while (index < s.length()) {
    //process
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to "put the string into a char array", you can use the string length as a limiter, and `charAt` to process each character:

```
for (int chPos = 0; chPos < str.length(); chPos++)
    doSomethingWith (str.charAt(chPos));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use String's .length() method.

```
String s = "test";   
for(int i=0; i < s.length ; i++){
   char c = s.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the String's method length to check the size of the string. 
for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char h = s.charAt(i);
    //process h
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use a for loop to iterate through all characters in the String until you get to String.length()
2. Use a foreach loop to iterate through all characters that are returned from String.getBytes()

Comment: Seems like a senseless reason to throw an Ecxception. Why not just iterate over the each element after determining the _length_ of the string.

Comment: Edited to offer options.

Comment: Remove the try/catch approach and I'll remove my downvote. You should not use Exceptions in this scenario.

Comment: I will remove, however it is a valid demonstration of technique, even if not for this exact example.

Comment: It is a possible approach, but it's a bad option here. We shouldn't teach the newb bad habits ;-)

Comment: I over-thought the question - I assumed that they already knew about the obvious String.length() approach and were looking for alternatives.